# ThreadPoolExecutor - how do I execute both functions func1 and func2 at the same time? I see that these are not getting executed one after the other

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
         task1 = executor.submit(func1,argument1,argument2)
         task2 = executor.submit(func2,argument1,argument2)
         #Note this Func2 doesn't return any value
         result1, result2 = task1.result()
         result3 = task2.result()
```

ThreadPoolExecutor - how do I execute both functions func1 and func2 at the same time? I see that these functions are getting executed one after the other and not simultaneously .

Also kindly note func1 returns value1,value2 but func2 doesn't return any value

Comment: Because of the global interpreter lock, using threads in Python is only a win for I/O-bound processes.  If your threads are CPU-bound (that is, they don't wait for I/O), then only one thread will execute at a time, and nothing is gained via threading.

Comment: If they are NOT executing one after the other then they are already executing at the same time. Your question is a contradiction.

Comment: You may want to look into [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) to avoid the issue that Tim Roberts has mentioned.

Comment: I got some pickling issue when I tried multiprocessing ProcessPoolExecutor

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.